# Postfix and smtpd_client_rate_limit to detect compromissed accounts

Tags: postfix, spam, rate-limiting

Some of our clients are administrators who need to send corporative messages to no more than 300 clients, specifying all of these clients together in the "To:" fields, instead of individual messages for each one. After that, postfix will "adjust" the message in order to delivery separate messages with only one "To:" recipients each.

So, I want to configure `anvil` parameters, taking into account this type of requirements for detecting compromised accounts. My doubt is, does Postfix consider an email of such characteristics (300 recipients) as only one "delivery requests"? (specifically, from the point of view of the `smtpd_client_message_rate_limit`).

Answer (score 1):

> My doubt is, does Postfix consider an email of such characteristics (300 recipients) as only one "delivery requests"?

**Yes**. In fact, the default limit of recipient per delivery request is 1000. See `postconf smtpd_recipient_limit` and the [man page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_limit)

If you want limit recipient, use [smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit).

A little note from [this page](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#conn_limit)

> IMPORTANT: These limits must not be used to regulate legitimate traffic: mail will suffer grotesque delays if you do so. The limits are designed to protect the smtpd(8) server against abuse by out-of-control clients.